# Font in silverlight for Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I want to use a font for textbox in my silverlight application for Windows Phone 7. The font isn't contained in the default font list.

Here is xaml code for applying the font to a textbox:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Height="95" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="527,78,0,0" Name="textBox" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" Width="70" FontFamily="/MyAppNamespace;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Papyrus"/>
```

The font is included in the folder Fonts.
The XAML view window for this page show exact font style that I want. But when I tried to deploy the app to my Samsung Omnia 7 the font used is still Segoe WP (the default font for text box).

So what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the font in your application.  The easiest way to do this is to go into Blend, select your TextBlock element, go to Text properties section, and click the Embed checkbox.  Note that if you're using a separate build server, this will require you to have the Blend SDK installed on that system.  (For font embedding, Blend uses a custom build target.  I believe it's the SDK adds this build target to the target system.)

The reason you're seeing Segoe WP is because your specified font is not found, so the runtime is falling back to a font it knows.  You haven't specified any fallback fonts, so it's using the default of Segoe WP.

Comment: As I said I included the font in the folder Fonts of my project, and the XAML view window in Visual Studio also show me the desired font in the text box. But when I deploy the app to my phone the font appeared is just the default font.

Comment: One more thing is that I created the Fonts folder and added the font by hand, but I thing it is not the problem because the XAML view can display the text with my added font.

Comment: What is the build action for the TTF file? How is it included in the csproj file? (show me the XML) Just including the file in the fonts folder is generally insufficient.

Comment: I'm guessing you copied some code from a sample. However, that original code was done in Blend. That means you cannot add the font by hand; you MUST embed it in Blend. The other option is to add the font file to your project and set the build action to Content and then change your XAML the "Fonts.zip#" portion.

Comment: I followed this tutorial for adding font to my app using Visual Studio http://www.markerstudio.com/technical/2011/06/windows-phone-7-custom-fonts/. The problem is still there: the XAML view displays correctly while my deploy app display default font. Is it possible that the Papyrus font can't be displayed in WP7?

Comment: Assuming the name of your font file is Papyrus.ttf and it has a build action of Content, change your FontFamily from "/MyAppNamespace;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Papyrus" to "/MyAppNamespace;component/Fonts/Papyrus.ttf".